# What is more preferable, creating dedicated domains for mobile apps that shares different content or associate them with folders in one domain?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, google-search, mobile

I want to consult you in an SEO matter which I am completely lost with.

I've built a social mobile application that allows users to share text content and made all the content that appears on the application available via the web through dedicated links. However, those links cannot be navigated through the website but they are generated when users shares content through the app to social media networks.

I've implemented this method on three applications with totally different content, and I've directed all generated URLs to be from the main company website which is `http://frootapps.com` so when users shares something, the URL will change to `http://frootapps.com/qareeb/share.aspx?data=127311`.

My question, which one is more preferable, a dedicated website for each app that uses such method? or it is ok to keep doing it the same way I am doing it?

Answer (score 1):

SEO is based more on quality than quantity. Links without anchor text relating both sites as being unique but relavent to one another will unlikely benefit you SEO-wise.

Also, the shared link will need to be picked up by the search engines in order to count. So from an SEO point-of-view, you're better off building "authority" for your single website than managing separate app websites without effective backlinking.

Answer (score 0):

if you're asking whether or not you should continue to redirect external links through your own proxy, I'd say that's not a bad idea. A lot of external links could be bad for SEO and masking them is a good way to ensure your website isn't negatively affected in SERPs because of them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much time you are willing to put into maintenance. If you think you can put aside enough time for maintenance of x amount of websites, it will be good to have a separate website for all your apps.

On the other hand, having a centralised website for all your domains would be a better idea if you have limited time for maintenance plus your brand will get an additional advantage of all your apps directing SEO juice towards your main domain which (having a powerful centralised domain), in my opinion is much more powerful than separate domains. Not to mention this will make maintenance much easier.

So, to answer your question in one sentence:
Yes, it is okay to keep doing it the way you have mentioned above.